# MVC C# Edit feature is adding instead of editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, edit

I included my code below, it is supposed to edit the record when you click the edit button but instead it adds a new record. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Data","Admin", new { id=data.Id })" id="launchBtn" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Data(int? id)
        {
            DataVM vm;
            if(id == null)
            {
                vm = new DataVM();
            }
            else
            {
                var dbData = _dataRepository.FindById(id.Value);
                vm = _mapper.Map<DadaVM>(dbData);
            }
            this.SetExistingDataFormList(vm);
            return View(vm);
        }

private void SetExistingDataFormList(ContentVM vm)
        {
            var datas = _dataRepository.GetDataEndpoints();

            foreach (var data in datas)
            {
                vm.Datas.Add(new DataVM
                {
                    Id = content.Id,
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: you should use if(id.HasValue) and not id == null

Comment: Shouldn't it be AddOrUpdate instead of Add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your SetExistingDataFormList method is only adding new elements, it doenst update them anywhere in the code. Also, where is the "content" variable?.

Also, use the HasValue property of your nullable int, not id == null.

Comment: For nullable variables `id==null` and `!id.HasValue` are equal

Comment: Yes, but whats the point in using id == null, if you could make it easier to read using the property available on every nullable object